# How to download file optimally

Tags: ios

I have files of approx 10MB. I need to download in an optimized way. So, is there any way to download it programmatically in optimized way?

Comment: What do you mean by optimize way?

Comment: It's not possible to answer without any details. There are so many ways to download files and so many criteria to classify as optimal. Tell OS, network locations, network speed, security concerns, etc.

Comment: i need to download it using ios on iphone.

Comment: If your boss / client told you "optimize the file download", you can't just repeat here the same question as we absolutely don't know your project and requirements, the subject of optimization (speed/bandwidth? resume interrupted downloads? wait until you get WiFi? etc); the type of the file (binary? text? image?); which protocol/formats you may support (zip? resampled media? http server supporting fragmented download?) etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question leaves a lot of room for interpretation. Here's a simple answer.

Use gzip.

Enable gzip on your web server. Most of them can do it. Send the accept-encoding: gzip header on your http request.

Generally this will get it done faster than uncompressed.